# Correct way to implement factories in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have different types of `Provider` (interface) classes say `ProviderA`, `ProviderB` and so on. In a normal world, I would create a class called `ProviderFactory` such that

```
public class ProviderFactory{
    public Provider getProviderByName(String providerName){
        for (Provider provider : availableProviders){
            if (provider.getName.equalIgnoreCase(providerName)){
                 return provider;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, What I want to know that are there any provided `annotations` to help me use this factory classes in singleton way ? These factories are static in nature and they can be configured at application runtime. So i am looking for singleton implementation here.

Answer (score 1):

`@Component`/`@Service`/`@Repository`/`@Controller`/`@RestController` are using singleton scope by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a factory pattern in Spring as shown below:

```
   @Component
    public class ProviderFactory {

        @Autowired
        private ProviderA providerA;

        @Autowired
        private ProviderB providerB;


        public static Provider getProviderByName(String providerName) {
            if (providerName.equalsIgnoreCase("providerA")) {
                return providerA;
            } else if (providerName.equalsIgnoreCase("providerB")) {
                return providerB;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate each `Provider` class with one of the stereotype annotations (`@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` or `@RestController`), then you can `@Autowire` them into your factory:

```
@Component
public class ProviderFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<Provider> availableProviders;

    public Provider getProviderByName(String providerName) {
        for (Provider provider : availableProviders) {
            if (provider.getName.equalIgnoreCase(providerName)){
                return provider;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, if you intend to use your `Provider` instances in other Spring beans, I would recommend to use `@Qualifier` in conjunction with `@Autowire` to let Spring solve which instance to use, e.g.

```
@Component
public class ClassThatDependsOnSpecificProvider {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("providerA")
    private Provider providerA;

}
```

More info about `@Qualifier` can be found in the [Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) chapter in the Spring reference docs.